# How do you type something on the same line of text in C

Tags: c, printf, scanf

I was wondering how can you type something in one line in C?

This is the normal way it outputs.

Output

```
 > 
 <text>
```

Instead

```
 > <text>
```

Comment: Using what source? Any normal output terminal obeys `\n`.

Comment: There is no "normal" way that C outputs. It does exactly what you tell it to do, but since you show no code we have no idea what you told it to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your tags, I'm guessing you're using printf().  Simply leave out the "\n" character, which means "newline.".

In other words.

`printf("> "); printf("text\n");`

This will print:

> > text

Comment: This is most likely it, I believe he is adding \n to the end of printf thinking it's necessary